# A question on morphisms of fields

Tags: field-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $A,B$ be two fields. Let $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ and $\psi:B\rightarrow A$ be two morphisms of fields. Can i conclude that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic fields?

My guess is yes, because every morphism of fields is injective, hence in this case $B$ contains an isomorphic copy of $A$, which in turns contains one copy of $B$. If this is right, how can i formalize it?

Comment: Unless you require a morphism of fields to be a morphism of unitary rings carrying the multiplicative unit to the mult. unit, the morphisms can be the zero ones and not injective...

Comment: @DonAntonio I require that

Comment: The question is a bit subtle. It is possible for a field that is infinite dimensional over its prime field to be isomorphic to  its proper subfield.

Comment: See Martin Brandenburg's answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39460/schroeder-bernstein-for-rings/39472#39472).

Comment: The tag "morphism" is a great achivement of this site!

Comment: @DonAntonio: Excuse me for the impolite tone. I do still think that although one can define lots of things, some lead to bizarre situations. Defining unital rings as a full subcategory of non-unital ones can be done (not requiring subrings to share their $1$), but many results require a more restricted notion; one could use $\Bbb Z$-algebras for that (but calling $\Bbb Z$-algebras unital rings, like $\Bbb Z$-modules are Abelian groups, has its charm). However if morphisms of fields can be zero, then images of field morphsims would not be subfields; this is very uncommon in algebraic categories

Comment: @DonAntonio: OK I've read, and I'll remove my comment. I also just realised that what I said about $\Bbb Z$-algebras is nonsense; the definition of $R$-algebra does not even require the existence of a $1$. What I meant is unital $\Bbb Z$-algebras, taken to also imply that homomorphisms preserve units...

Comment: Dear @DonAntonio, I'm sorry that you don't like the ring with $0=1$ but I'm afraid you'll have to coexist with it: I don't think that in 2013 there is one active algebraic geometer or commutative algebraist in the world who would deny that this ring exists . Excluding it would exclude the empty scheme from scheme theory, which is exactly as (un)reasonable as excluding the empty set from set theory. On the other hand I don't think there has **ever** existed **one** book on field theory which  claimed that this ring with $0=1$ is a field.

Comment: Oh, I don't care about it almost at all, dear @GeorgesElencwajg, though I'm sure a huge lot of mathematicians plainly and sheerly erase it from their schedule, and even algebraic geometers won't cry a lot, me thinks, if the victim of denying axiomatically $\,0=1\,$ in ring theory is a such a non-transcendental being as the empty scheme...OTOH I can't tell about *all* the books on field theory, but I think you're right in that, and good if it is so.

Comment: Dear @YACP, do you mean yourself? I quite agree  and we are in very good company: Bourbaki calls these structures without unit element "pseudorings" and Jacobson calls them "rngs": probably a joke based on the fact that the capital letter "I" typographically looks like the unity  $1$ of a ring, so that a "ring" without unity should be denoted by the word "RING" without the letter "I" . Again, I don't think that there are  any algebraic geometers or commutative algebraists (of whom you are a  distinguished representative) who would call "rings" these structures without $1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of two non-isomorphic fields which embed inside each other](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929118/example-of-two-non-isomorphic-fields-which-embed-inside-each-other)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an occasion, when instincts developed over finite extensions of (prime) fields lead one astray.

The first counterexamples that come to mind need a bit of background from the theory of elliptic curves. It is quite possible for there to be isogenies going back and forth between two non-isomorphic elliptic curves, $E_1$ and $E_2$. The isogenies give rise to embeddings between the corresponding function fields 
$K(E_1)$ and $K(E_2)$ (take for example $K=\mathbb{C}$ to avoid several algebraic pitfalls). Yet, if the two elliptic curves are not isomorphic, the functions fields won't be isomorphic either.

Comment: See Robin Chapman's answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39460/schroeder-bernstein-for-rings/39470#39470).

Comment: Rats, should've guessed that this has been done somewhere in these parts.

Comment: Actually it suffices to have an isogeny going one way, because there is always the dual isogeny.

Comment: Don't worry about rats, dear Jyrki, that was a brilliant answer (+1) and if Robin Chapman had the same idea, that was brilliant of him too. Isn't life wonderful?